# MS Access query select one of 2 columns based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, logic, linear-algebra

I have an MS Access table that contains 2 columns [Issued Email] and [Email].
Generally, both columns should have the same data, but in some cases only [Issued Email] contains the data OR [Email]. I want to filter that out, so that my query shows only rows, where one or both of the columns shows an email address and where both are NOT empty.

Example table (TableA):

```
Issued Email       Email
-----------------  ----------------
abc123@gmail.com   abc123@gmail.com
EMPTY              def456@mgail.com
null               null
ghi@gmail.com      null
EMPTY              null
```

Result shall be:

```
Filtered Email
--------------
abc123@gmail.com
def456@mgail.com
ghi@gmail.com
```

So I not only have to compare against a null value but also for the occurence of the string 'EMPTY' in both columns.

What I have at the moment, is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE
(TableA.[Issued Email] IS NOT NULL OR TableA.[Issued Email] NOT LIKE 'EMPTY')
AND 
(TableA.[Email] IS NOT NULL OR TableA.[Email] NOT LIKE 'EMPTY');
```

However, this doesn't filter out rows, that contain EMPTY and/or null in both columns, which makes sense, because I only compare the same column with itself.

So I thought:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE
(TableA.[Issued Email] IS NOT NULL OR TableA.[Email] IS NOT NULL)
AND 
(TableA.[Issued Email] NOT LIKE 'EMPTY' OR TableA.[Email] NOT LIKE 'EMPTY');
```

but this throws me an error "Data type conflict in criteria expression".
I don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on below `UNION` query

```
SELECT [Issued Email] as ValidMail FROM TableA WHERE [Issued Email] Like '*@*';   
  UNION 
SELECT Email as ValidMail FROM TableA WHERE Email Like '*@*';
```